# BST tree using integers

Tags: java

I have to implement a BST tree in java and I am using this code:

```
    ArrayDeque a = new ArrayDeque();    

    a.add(root); // to add root to queue
    a.add(new Node(null)); // to add newline node
```

but I am getting this error: Constructor Node in class Node cannot be applied to given types (because of the null) as i am using integers not strings. Can someone help me please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cast your `null` to a data type that `Node` does accept. Example: `((String)null)`.

Comment: Pls, show the rest of the code (in particular, Node's code)

Comment: public Node(int new) 
    {
        r = null;
        no = new;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the default constructor

```
public Node() {
    // initialize Node with the internal representation
    // of newline node
}
```

or change the constructor

```
public Node(int nodeValue) { ... };
```

to

```
public Node(Integer nodeValue) { ... };
```

Then you will be able to pass null as argument because now new is an Object and can be null.

Comment: new is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @75inchpianist yes you are right. My focus was on the int to Integer change. I'll correct it, thank you.